# How to add the picture to graph without overlapping?

Tags: plotting, graphics, image-processing, overlay, size

I want to add some pictures to my plot and point them to especial part of the graph with the arrow (or maybe something fancier) but I got problem the canvas of my pictures are too big and its cover part of axes and arrow. how can solve this problem? also, I think maybe put the picture in the circle and show them look like magnified part of the graph. is that possible in Mathematica? 
[image]

Comment: You tag image have a alpha channel?I think `RemoveBackground` can help a little.

Comment: Cropping the inset image will surely help a lot. Look at `ImageCrop`

Answer (score 2):

First, of all people in MSE need data and/or code to try to help you. So be always aware  to ask a question with gives the minimum effort to the one who will try to answer --- I have use an image which was on my computer. In the following case, as I use a random draw to look like your graphic --- I would have used a white noise to be more like yours data ---, the positionning of the elements are always recomputed. So the circle and the arrow will not be where you expect them to be.

But you can change it. Here is the code

```
\[ScriptCapitalP] = 
TransformedProcess[b[t] + 10, b \[Distributed] WienerProcess[], t];
data = RandomFunction[\[ScriptCapitalP], {0, 4, 0.01}, 1]
```

Keep those command in a separate cell. Now

```
a = ListLinePlot[data, AxesOrigin -> {0, 5}, PlotRange -> {5, 13}];
b = Graphics[{Red, Disk[{1., 10.05}, .1]}];
c = Graphics[{Blue, Arrow[{{1.1, 9.8}, {2, 7}}]}];
img = Magnify[Import["C:\\000moi\\ecopub\\moebpeint.jpg"], 0.25];
d = Graphics[Inset[img, {2.4, 6.5}], Frame -> False];
Show[a, b, d, c, AspectRatio -> Automatic]
```

Here is the result

[image]

Comment: Thank you, Cyrille.piatecki for you answer, the data file for this graph is too big I could not upload the data here.